# Refresh or Reload fragment in ViewPager on clicking the checkbox

Tags: android, android-viewpager, refresh, fragment

I want to change the string value serviceName = negative while clicking negative checkbox and to while checking positive checkbox,so it took dynamicaly value from server.

```
"http://172.25.xx.yy:8080/SampleRestService/rest/hello/messages/"+StaticValue.sample+"/"+ serviceName +")).get();
```

Here I want to change the serviceName to positive or negative when clicking  the checkBox positive r negative respectively.

Error:I am usingViewPager.
 Value is not passing to serviceName while clicking on checkbox.Did I want to refresh the fragment or any other way to pass the value

Juz i want to change the value of service to negative when checkbox is clicked the value is changing but the fragment is not reloading as it is in viewPager so it remains serviceName =positive itself....

```
    package com.db.socialmedia;
    //implements OnItemSelectedListener
    public class MessageNegative extends Fragment {
    CheckBox positive_checkbox ;
    CheckBox negative_checkbox ;
    public String[] Message;
    public String[] Date;

    private Spinner  Category_spinner;
     public GraphicalView messagesview;

        public static String serviceName="positive";
        private ArrayList<String> messagesNegativeArray=null;
        private ArrayList<String> dateAndTime=null;

      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messaged, container, false);

        boolean isChecked = true;
        positive_checkbox = (CheckBox)V.findViewById(R.id.layout_Message_positive_checkbox);
        negative_checkbox = (CheckBox)V.findViewById(R.id.layout_Message_negative_checkbox);

        //To make positive as default selected
            positive_checkbox.setChecked(isChecked);

        // Inorder to make single selection of check box
            positive_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public  void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){

                 positive_checkbox.setChecked(true);
                 negative_checkbox.setChecked(false);
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),     "positive clicked", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }}
            });
            System.out.println("0");
            negative_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public  void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                     positive_checkbox.setChecked(false);
                     negative_checkbox.setChecked(true);
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),     "negative clicked", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }}
                }); 





            negative_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //          MessagePositive.serviceName="neagtive";         }
            });


            positive_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //          MessagePositive.serviceName="positive";         }
            });

            //service
            try{

                String restServiceResponse= new RestServiceManager().execute(
                        "http://172.25/SampleRestService/rest/hello/messages/"+StaticValue.sample+"/"+ serviceName +")).get();
                System.out.println(restServiceResponse);

            //positive.setText(negativeValue);
            //Toast.makeText(this, restServiceResponse, 2000).show();
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(restServiceResponse);
            JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObject1.getJSONArray("messagesStatusArray");
            messagesNegativeArray=new ArrayList<String>();
            dateAndTime=new ArrayList<String>();


            for(int messageNegative=0;messageNegative<jsonArray2.length();messageNegative++)
            {
                messagesNegativeArray.add(jsonArray2.getJSONObject(messageNegative).getString("messagesStatus"));
....
....


/------------------------------------------------------
This is my ViewPager
//--------------------------------------------------
Here MessagePositive fragment class will be called...


package com.db.socialmedia;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import com.db.socialmedia.R;
import com.db.socialmedia.FirstFragment;
import com.db.socialmedia.FirstFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * * The <code>ViewPagerFragmentActivity</code> class is the fragment activity
 * hosting the ViewPager * @author mwho
 */

public class ViewPagerFragmentAOrganisation extends Fragment {
    /** maintains the pager adapter */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    public static View android;
    public static ViewPager pager,pagerN;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc) * @see
     * android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, container, false);
        // initialsie the pager
        this.initialisePaging();
        return android;
    }

    /** * Initialise the fragments to be paged */



public  void initialisePaging() {
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            //fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(),SAPiechartTab.class.getName()));

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity  (),BarChartOrganisation.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivit(),SentimentAnalysisOrganisation.class.getName()));
 fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(),MessagePositive.class.getName()));
            this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getChildFragmentManager(),
                    fragments);

            //

        pager = (ViewPager) android.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

         pager = (ViewPager) android.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
            }

    public void setPager(int currentPosition) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, elaborate your question and make your code more readable ... Do you really need to refresh your Fragment ? Or just need to call a method from where your service could be called ?

Comment: Juz i want to change the value of service to negative when checkbox is clicked the value is changing but the fragment is not reloading as it is in viewPager so it remains serviceName =positive itself....